# Wifi router blocks wireless peers from connecting each other

Tags: router, wireless-networking, firewall

What option controls that wifi router blocks wifi peers from connecting each other.

I have wifi router Dlink Dir-320. With that router I can't ping (or connect via FTP or HTTP) one laptop from another laptop. But I can ping/connect other PCs connected with wire.

[image]

If I use different router that I can ping/connect from one laptop to another laptop.

I studied Dlink Dir-620 settings and I can't find anything that controls it.

I wish to know what settings do that because I wish to have router that will allow internet only connections for my quests. I wish to give wifi access to my guests but I wish to stay protected from hacking, sniffering.
Blocking wifi-wifi connections is not enough. I wish to block wifi users from connecting wired clients. Wired users must have internet access only as well.

Also I wish to allow peers to peers connection when my guests have gone. Including wifi-wifi.

I am ready to use dd-wrt, openwrt router if they have such option. May be iptables command?

Comment: The option is usually called "client isolation"

Comment: DD-WRT has it, calls it *AP isolation*. You can find it described here, http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Advanced_wireless_settings#AP_Isolation. If you plan on doing anything fancy with your router, you should seriously consider getting a router which can be flashed with DD-WRT, OpenWRT, or Tomato firmware.

Comment: I have dd-wrt router DIR-320. But DIR-620 does not have stable *wrt firmware. `It seems there is no option like `client isolation`. So it is On for wireless clients by default and there is no way to turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually an option called "Wireless Isolation", "Client Isolation", "Wireless client separation" among others.

Comment: Wireless isolation won't isolate wired from wireless clients.

Comment: @Ron - you would be surprised... different routers call it different things, I have seen wireless isolation on some routers meaning that it isolates wireless stations from each other.

Comment: Yes, me too.  but as you say it isolates wireless from each other.  I have never seen it isolate wireless from wired.

Answer (score 1):

DD-WRT can isolate wireless clients from each other, but it will NOT isolate wired and wireless clients -- they can still communicate.

In order to block wireless clients from talking to wired clients, you will need to create separate VLANs for your "internal" and guest networks and apply filtering between them.  Those features are usually only available on commercial grade products.